# Redefining existing mapping

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I have Customer and Address tables and entities with one-to-many relationship (customer have multiple addresses).
I can't change Customer and Address entities. I need to add one property to Customer and Address so I'm using ExtendedCustomer and ExtendedAddress entities, discriminating them on EntitiyType column, and they both have ExtensionUID property mapped in the SubclassMap. I added this columns to SQL tables.

```
public class ExtendedCustomer :Customer
{
    public virtual string ExtensionUID  { get; set; }
}

public class ExtendedCustomerMap : CustomerMap
{
    public ExtendedCustomerMap ()
    {
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("EntityType", (byte)0).Not.Nullable();                                     
    }
}

public class ExtendedCustomerSubclassMap : SubclassMap<ExtendedCustomer>
{
    public ExtendedCustomerSubclassMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue(1);
        Map(x => x.ExtensionUID);            
    }
}

//Same stuff for Address/ExtendedAddress
```

All this above works.

Now, the problems is that Customer defines property `IList<Address> Addresses`. When I look at the instance of ExtendedCustomer in the debugger, Addresses contains the list of instances of ExtendedAddress but I can't access ExtensionUID property of the Addresses in code.

Can I somehow redefine the Address property to be `IList<ExtendedAddress> Addresses` so I can use ExtensionUID property?

I tried just adding `new IList<ExtendedAddress> Addresses` but nhibernate fails to map this (Unable to cast...).
I added `IList<ExtendedAddress> ExtendedAddresses` property and defined the mapping like this: `HasMany(x => x.ExtendedAddresses).KeyColumn("CustomerId").AsBag();` and this works but now I have two collections with the same data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i think, you should edit your mapping files.Can you share your mapping to us?

And your Customer mapping file can like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
namespace="YourNameSpace" assembly="YourAssemblyName">

<class name="Customer" table="Customer">
<id name = "ID">
  <generator class = "native"/>
</id>

  <property name="Name"/>
<property name="SurName" />
<bag name ="Address"  lazy="true" cascade ="save-update" inverse ="false">
  <key column ="CustomerID"/>
  <one-to-many class ="Address"/>
</bag>

</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```